# How to copy a function/list/array without reference

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have code that runs in a loop to generate a function that has values assigned every multiple of a user-supplied step size. I want to copy the final function "value-wise" to a different function so that I can run the loop again (overwriting the dummy function) with new initial conditions and compare the plots. The naive `r1 = r` code seems to pass the functions by reference: when the code has finished running, all of the functions are linked as `r1 = r2 = r3 = r`. How do I "clone" the output lists without maintaining this unwanted linkage?

As a side note, I am not sure what to call the object I have created; it is generated by a loop assigning values by `r[i] = ...`. Is this a list, an array, or a function?

Comment: What you made is a set of indexed down-values for the variable `r`. You can verify this by evaluating `Downvalues[r]`. If you are getting `r[1] = r[2] = ...`, then there is something wrong with the way you doing assignment to `r` in your loop. Note: if you wanted `r` to hold an array of values, you should be using `r[[i]]` rather than `r[i]`. I can't say more than this without seeing code, which I urge you to add to your question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. My code is very long, and I think the actual structure of the loop is not too relevant. To clarify: the loop works fine, and there are different values assigned to r[1], r[2], etc. that plot nicely. I would like to then "copy" this set of values to another called "r1" so that r[1]=r1[1], r[2]=r1[2], etc. The initial conditions are then changed and the loop is run again, overwriting the values in the list "r". I want this to not change "r1".

Comment: Why not use a second index? For example, r[1,1] would be the first one, r[1,2] the second, r[1,3] etc. Now run your loop again and assign to r[2,1], r[2,2], r[2, 3], etc. Continue until you have them all.

Comment: I may go back into the code and do just this. The reason I haven't done this is because the loop refers to functions that involve the letters themselves, and I would have to restructure my code. It is a fourth order Runge-Kutta program numerically integrating equations for four variables ("r", "T", "P", and "L") that all depend on each other in complicated ways. I may make these lists "two-dimensional" if there is no straightforward way to "clone" the resultant values after one round of integration.